# F# string to enum conversion

Tags: string, enums, f#, type-conversion

I have the following enum located in public class `MyClass` in namespace `MyNamespace` in a C#.NET DLL I reference and open from my F# module:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    ValueA,
    ValueB,
    ValueC}
```

I want to convert string `s` to its `MyEnum` equivalent (if possible) in my F# module. Trying to achieve it like...

```
let myEnumValue = (MyClass.MyEnum) (Enum.Parse(typedefof<MyClass.MyEnum>, s))
```

...gives me *Invalid use of a type name and/or object constructor. If necessary use 'new' and apply the constructor to its arguments...* error. Same if I use `typeof<MyClass.MyEnum>` instead of `typedefof<MyClass.MyEnum>`. Trying...

```
let myEnumValue = (typedefof<MyClass.MyEnum>) (Enum.Parse(typedefof<MyClass.MyEnum>, s))
```

...or...

```
let myEnumValue = (typeof<MyClass.MyEnum>) (Enum.Parse(typedefof<MyClass.MyEnum>, s))
```

... gives me *The value is not a function and cannot be applied* error.
I use `MyEnum` fine in other parts of my F# code, so I guess there is no problem with my C#.NET DLL.

And to avoid some likely questions :-)

- I need converting string to enum because certain `MyEnum` values are
  serialised into an XML using `.ToString()` and the enums deserialised
  from XML will be passed on as parameters to an F# function
- Using    the `int` equivalent of `MyEnum` to write to and read from
  the XML is undesirable because the XML should be human-readable, plus it is more    likely for the `int` equivalents of `MyClass`
  values to change than    for those of `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your code is the way that you are trying to cast the Object (returned by the Parse method) into an instance of MyClass.MyEnum. The syntax you attempted results in an "invalid use of a type name" error.

In F#, you down-cast as follows:

```
let myEnumValue = Enum.Parse(typedefof<MyClass.MyEnum>, s) :?> MyClass.MyEnum
```